# Visualize branches on GitHub

Tags: git, github, branch

In TortoiseGit, gitk or on BitBucket, it is common to have a visualization of the project history with all the branches, like this:

[image]

However, GutHub's commit history seems to be flat, at least I couldn't find a way to display this kind of graph. Can the GitHub's web UI somehow visualize branches like other Git clients commonly can?

Comment: Edit: GitHub has since restored the service. `/network` behaves as expected. As of 2019-May-01: Network graph deprecated. No information given in the changelog. No replacement offered. Update: GitHub changelog no longer contains entry for deprecating the feature, but the feature still does not work.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

You can see a graph, but without commit messages in `Insights` => `Network` section (commit messages with authors are shown on hover).

Note: this works for public repos or GitHub Enterprise only!

Example: https://github.com/google/orbit/network
[image: Network grap]

Comment: Note that the Network tab is currently placed under the Graphs tab within the GitHub UI

Comment: Note this shows both forks and branches in those forks. If there are too many of them, it refuses to display them at all, for instance with https://github.com/python/cpython/network

Comment: As a shortcut, just add `/network` in the url after your repo name

Comment: Note that it is now under the `Insights` tab

Comment: On a private repository, adding `/network` to the URL shows "Forks" and tells me that no one has forked the repository yet. But I don't care about forks. I just want to see the different branches, development paths, and merges. How can I do that in GitHub?

Comment: @GarretWilson that's a limitation of private non-Pro github repos. You still can see the branches in bitbucket private repos.

Comment: @RuslanOstafiichuk thank you, but that sure is a letdown for teaching my software development class. We had been using Bitbucket, which has a decent graph to show students how Git works. We're switching to GitHub, but now my students won't be able to see a graph of their repository unless they make their homework public, which for obvious reasons I don't want them to do.

Comment: Github removed this feature today. This is no longer possible.

Comment: @killjoy link from the answer is still working https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand/network

Comment: Looks like they undid the changes. The blog post that announced the removal is gone now.

Comment: this only works for public repos or having GitHub Enterprise!

Answer (score 24):

You could use Le Git Graph, a browser extension that does exactly this.

[image: Screenshot]

Install the extension from here : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/le-git-graph-commits-grap/joggkdfebigddmaagckekihhfncdobff

It will add a new "commits" section to every GitHub repo you open. Open the commits graph and there, all commits across branches will be listed along with the git graph.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Hope it helps!

Comment: The extension _Le Git Graph_ has a beautiful look, and gives exactly what is needed.

Unfortunately I do not see it fit for private repositories. For public repositories it should work great, even though I have not tested it.

If it had been rewritten to accept a personal access token (PAT) (e.g. the same way as [Refined GitHub](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github) does), a fine-grained token could have been supplied, but authenticate directly (through your server) as a user is unfortunately a big no-go for me.

Comment: Feature request for Le Git Graph: https://github.com/NirmalScaria/le-git-graph/issues/33